# Assuming $m \ge 3$, under what conditions is $z^{m-1} = \frac{x^m + y^m}{x + y}$?

Tags: polynomials, exponentiation

One case where this is true is $z=1$:

$$(1)^{m-1} = \frac{1^m + 1^m}{1+1}$$

Another case is where $x=y$:

$$(x)^{m-1} = \frac{x^m + x^m}{x+x}$$

Assuming that $x,y,z,m$ are positive integers with $z > 1, m \ge 3$, gcd$(x,y)=1$, is it ever the case that:

$$z^{m-1} = \frac{x^m + y^m}{x+y}$$

How would one go about solving for this situation or proving that there are no solutions?

If $z > 1$, then there exists positive integers $a,b$ such that $z=a+b$

$$(a+b)^{m-1} = a^{m-1} + {{m-1} \choose 2}a^{m-2}b + \dots + b^{m-1} = x^{m-1} - x^{m-2}y + \dots + y^{m-1}$$

I can see that $a+b < x+y$.  I'm trying to see if there is a next logical step to take to make progress.

Is there a standard solution for this type of question?  Does anyone have any tips on how to proceed on analyzing this type of problem?

---

Edit: Updated the question based on a comment.

Comment: You always have a solution for $x=y$, so you probably want to restrict your attention to coprime $x$ and $y$.

Comment: for $m=3$ the complete solution is given by the polynomials:$x =k(-n^2 -2mn) y = k(m^2 −n^2) z = k(mn+m^2+n^2)$

Comment: Thanks very much.  I didn't think of applying the solution to Pythagorean triples. :-) I'll update my question to assume $m \ge 5$

Comment: This will be very hard, for $m=5$ this is equivalent to :$$ 4.19.(x+y)^4+( 5(x-y)^2-3(x+y)^2)^2= 20z^4 $$ and this seems very difficult (equation $ax^4+by^4=cz^2$).